# What do the letters 'u' and 'v', representing nodes in networkx documentation, stand for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am exploring Python's NetworkX library. In all the documentation I find the letters `u` and `v` representing nodes. E.g. `Graph.add_edge(u_of_edge, v_of_edge, **attr)` (add an edge between 'u' and 'v'), `G.edges[u, v]` (*"'edge' is of the form (u, v) where 'u' and 'v' are the tail and head of the edge"*), and so on.

What do these letters stand for? They seem totally arbitrary, they are quite unusual, and I can't make any sense of them. For descriptive purposes, at least, I would expect e.g. `node1`, `node2` or `n1`, `n2`. So, I suppose there must be some reason for using those letters. E.g. are they used in mathematics or another field as a standard notation?

Comment: This does not seem like "standard" notation. I have seen much more sensible notations for nodes but never 'u' and 'v'!  Otherwise, I wouldn't have asked!  See, e.g. https://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter6/6.1.html

Comment: Some examples where u, v are used: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgraph-theory%5D+u+v, https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/40210/40210_F12/CGT_early.pdf, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29, https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/21-228/lec10.pdf, ...

Comment: The links you provided are just mentioning 'u' and 'v', like a dozen ones I found around, all of which are **just propagating these notations.**  When I asked for a **standard reference** it was for one that talks about definitions and notations in networkds and graphs, like the one I brought up. In which the letters 'a', 'b', etc. are used, which are **natural**,  make sense. and are used for a lot of cases that call for a letter enumeration. Instead, 'u' and 'v' are very specific, totally arbitrary, unnatural and make no sense. That's all. **Very simple**.

Comment: Edited some comments here to remove incorrect assertions that this question is off-topic. It isn't. Asking a non-opinionated clarification question about the meanings of terms in documentation for programming libraries is absolutely on-topic for Stack Overflow. We do not deem questions off-topic because they are already answered elsewhere. If you'd like to discuss the matter of topicality further, take it to [Meta], not comments here.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to partially answer here. 
In graph theory, the letter `V` is used for **'vertex'** which is another name for nodes. 
`E` will be used for 'edges' and `G` for the graph.
It stands to reason, within all this letters, that `U` is used because it's alphabetically close to `V`.
So the edge `E` is connected to the nodes (vertices) `U` and `V`.

Comment: OK, 'v' for vertex makes sense. But 1) it is capitalized and 2) your explanation for the letter' 'u' is incongruous with the that of 'V'. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: the uppercase is used when you are representing the ensemble of vertices. The lowercase when you are talking about a specific one :)

Comment: OK. Thank you .